# Email to be accepted in 2 formats i.e. abc.def AND abc.def@testdomain.com

Tags: php, validation, email, yii

I need emails to be validated as a EMAIL(abc.def@testdomain.com) and at the same time as a USERNAME (abc.def). I have used Yii EMAIL Validation which is strict validation but i have not to change it because it is using in many other places in the project.

However, i need to add CUSTOM USERNAME VALIDATION along with YII EMAIL VALIDATION for a single MODEL.

Below is the Code to do that.

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = array(
        array('email', 'required', 'message'=>'Please complete {attribute}'),
        array('email', 'EmailCustom'),
        array('email', 'unique')
    );
}
```

Whereas EmailCustom Validator Class is:

```
class EmailCustom extends CEmailValidator
{
    public $pattern = '/^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?[ ]*$/';

    protected function validateAttribute($object, $attribute)
    {
        $pattern = '/^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?[ ]*$/';
        if ($object->visitor_card_status == 2) {
            if (!preg_match($pattern, $object->$attribute)) {
                if ($object->$attribute !== $object->first_name . '.' . $object->last_name) {
                    $this->addError($object, $attribute, 'Email is incorrect format');
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!preg_match($pattern, $object->$attribute)) {
                $this->addError($object, $attribute, 'Email is incorrect format');
            }
        }
    }

    public function clientValidateAttribute($object, $attribute)
    {
        if ($this->validateIDN)
        {
            Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('punycode');
            // punycode.js works only with the domains - so we have to extract it before punycoding
            $validateIDN='
                            var info = value.match(/^(.[^@]+)@(.+)$/);
                            if (info)
                                value = info[1] + "@" + punycode.toASCII(info[2]);
                            ';
        } else {
            $validateIDN = '';
        }

        $message = $this->message!==null ? $this->message : Yii::t('yii','{attribute} is not in a recognised format. <span style="text-transform:capitalize;">Please </span>revise.');
        $message = strtr($message, array(
            '{attribute}'=>$object->getAttributeLabel($attribute),
        ));
}
```

So, What should be added in the pattern of Validator Class to accept only two FORMATS:   **abc.def**  and **abc.def@testdomain.com**

Hope to hear from you soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have updated the pattern which accepts both the formats and using the Yii Validator function does the trick.

Below is the pattern to accept both the format. i.e. abc.def and string@testdomain.com

```
/(^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?[ ]*$)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
```

I hope it may help others. Thanks